# Navigation between rows in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have created a sqlite database which is loaded in `DataGrid` but I have two Next and Previous Buttons, it is easy to navigated between data and show it to corresponding textbox in Windows Forms with `DataGridView` but I am unable to find a way to do same in `DataGrid` .

Here is my sql database code -

```
string dbConnectionString = @"Data Source=emsdatabase.db;version=3;";
```

Loading data into DataGrid :

```
SQLiteConnection sqliteCon = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnectionString);
try
{
    sqliteCon.Open();
    string Query = "select Eid,Name,Mobile,Gender,Email from employeeinfo";
    SQLiteCommand createCommand = new SQLiteCommand(Query, sqliteCon);
    createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdp = new SQLiteDataAdapter(createCommand);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("employeeinfo");
    dataAdp.Fill(dt);
    TableDataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    dataAdp.Update(dt);

    sqliteCon.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

I can display selected data in corresponding textboxes:

```
DataGrid gd = (DataGrid)sender;
DataRowView rowSelected = gd.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
if (rowSelected != null)
{
    EidTextBox.Text = rowSelected["Eid"].ToString();
    NameTextBox.Text = rowSelected["Name"].ToString();
    MobileTextBox.Text = rowSelected["Mobile"].ToString();                
    GenderTextBox.Text = rowSelected["Gender"].ToString();
    EmailTextBox.Text = rowSelected["Email"].ToString();
}
```

But Unable to show corresponding data on textbox on next or previous button click

```
private void PrevButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //?????
}

private void NextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //?????
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to change SelectedIndex or SelectedItem.

```
private void PreviousClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (TableDataGrid.SelectedIndex > 0)
        TableDataGrid.SelectedIndex--;
}

private void NextClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (TableDataGrid.SelectedIndex < TableDataGrid.Items.Count - 1)
        TableDataGrid.SelectedIndex++;
}
```

We can find previous and next DataRowView in DataView (except when very first or last rows are selected respectively). If navigation is possible, then change DataGrid.SelectedItem:

```
private void PreviousClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView rowSelected = TableDataGrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
    if (rowSelected == null)
        return;
    int idx = GetDataRowViewIndex(rowSelected);
    if (idx > 0)
        TableDataGrid.SelectedItem = rowSelected.DataView[idx - 1];
}

private void NextClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView rowSelected = TableDataGrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
    if (rowSelected == null)
        return;
    int idx = GetDataRowViewIndex(rowSelected);
    if (idx < rowSelected.DataView.Count - 1)
        TableDataGrid.SelectedItem = rowSelected.DataView[idx + 1];
}

int GetDataRowViewIndex(DataRowView row)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row.DataView.Count; i++)
        if (row.DataView[i] == row)
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: thanks its working fine, but before i mark it as answer , is there any way to auto select first item of grid so next or previous button work without pointing cursor to data of grid ?

Comment: set `TableDataGrid.SelectedIndex=0;` after `TableDataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;`. If first rows is selected, Previous button won't work. there is nowhere for it to go

Comment: Thanks :) its okay whoever uses prev. button first , thank you for get rid out of this issue

Comment: @sachinshinde, please see my edit. it is actually simpler to change SelectedIndex :)